# python pandas read_excel return an AssertionError: importing a file with images

Tags: python, pandas

I can't use the read_excel method from pandas library in my Ipython note book.
After some test and cleaning in the Excel file, I understood their is a complete column of drawings (or images). When I deleted this column I stop the error message. Does somebody know how to configure read_excel option to collect only dataes? This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
# File selection
userfilepath = r'C:\Temp'
filename = "exportCS12.xlsx"
filenameCS12 = os.path.join(userfilepath, filename)
print(filenameCS12)
# workbook upload
df = pd.read_excel(filenameCS12, sheetname='Sheet1')
```

Answer (score -1):

Pandas import was not working due to a none clean excel file. Problem sovlve with openpyxl, able to navigate in excel only in validated areas.